# Homebrew doctor warnings requesting library deletions

Tags: macos, homebrew

I got the following list of `brew doctor` warnings and was wondering if it's safe to  delete the libraries and .pc files listed. (I have no idea what they are used for!)

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
/usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

Comment: The only way we could answer this is if we knew what installed them and then what uses them.

Comment: Apparently, the libraries come from installing R.app http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122558/making-homebrew-and-r-app-live-together-happily

Comment: Then this is a dup and as my comment there says Something is very likely to break and none but you will be in a position to debug it - which is why those who know how to debug this don't use a package manger that puts things where you also build - they know how to debug having done this before

Comment: Your comment isn't of much use to me, but thanks for your effort anyway!

Comment: The answer is it is not safe as something will break but you might not get told what goes wrong until you see a wrong answer in some report although more likely a crash

Comment: If I want to keep things safe, does that essentially mean that I have to chose between using R or using Homebrew?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same warnings, and worked it around with the following:

So first back up these files:

`mv /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib.bak
...`

Then install tcl/tk with Homebrew:

`brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install tcl-tk --with-tk`

Then link the files, so that R can find the tcl/tk installed by Homebrew:

`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.1/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.1/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib`

Please double check that the linked location is where tcl-tk is installed.

Now both Homebrew and R are happy.

More details can be found [on my blog](http://azaleasays.com/2014/08/25/homebrew-warnings-about-unbrewed-dylibs-installed-by-r/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warnings from `brew doctor`. To get rid of R that I had installed via the cran package, I basically followed the same steps as Olivier, thus removing app and framework as described in the [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) manual:

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript
```

Then I carefully removed the files listed as belonging to the package by **making sure that no directories were deleted** (especially the complete `usr` branch, which is listed in the output of `pkgutil` -- delete this one and you will get a kernel panic):

```
for F in `pkgutil --files org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11 | sed 's/^/\//'`
  do if [[ -f $F ]]
    then rm $F
  fi
done
```

This left me with few Tcl and Tk-related directories in `/usr/local/lib`, which I got rid off **manually**, checking the output from `pkgutil`. Alternatively, but risking to remove unrelated directories that for whatever reason were left empty, this could be done via:

```
find /usr/local -type d -empty -delete
```

I reinstalled R through `brew install r` without problems.

Comment: Alternatively, Oliviers answer works fine if one adds the `--only-files` flag to `pkgutil` to make sure no directories are removed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the intention of uninstalling R completely from my Mac and re-installing it using Homebrew.

**CAUTION: DON'T FOLLOW THESE STEPS**
***Please read to the end of the post before taking any action.***

The steps I took were as follows:

1) Remove the R app and framework:

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript
```

2) Remove the packages accompanying R (my understanding was that R installed some packages). On my system, I identified the following packages:

```
$ pkgutil --pkgs | grep org.r-
org.r-project.R.Leopard.fw.pkg
org.r-project.R.Leopard.GUI.pkg
org.r-project.R.Leopard.GUI64.pkg
org.r-project.R.x86_64.fw.pkg
org.r-project.R.x86_64.GUI.pkg
org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11
```

To see which files make up the Tcl/Tk package, for example, you may type:

```
pkgutil --files org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11
```

I used the following command to remove all the files and (sub-)folders from that package:

```
# DO NOT RUN THIS it will delete /usr
# pkgutil --files org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11 | xargs sudo rm -rf
```

That turned out to be a very bad idea as it resulted in a kernel panic and I ended up having to re-install Mavericks!  Apparently, according to the geniuses at the Apple Store, the above packages come pre-installed with Mavericks and, for some unknown reason, deleting the files from the above mentioned package removes some essential system files!

I concluded that using Homebrew causes a lot more trouble instead of making my life easier!  Originally, I dumped MacPorts for Homebrew because Homebrew was faster and MacPorts seemed to keep a lot of "leaves" on its trees! Also, both require regular maintenance.

Finally, I'm giving up both!

Comment: This answer is potentially dangerous.  @Olivier, can you please edit it to include a header that explicitly says something like **DON'T FOLLOW THIS ADVICE!!!**.  The reason is that someone careless or rushed might follow your steps before reaching the **this caused a kernel panic and I had to reinstall Mavericks**!  I would edit it, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: `pkgutil --files ...` also lists parent directories, not just files, so when you fed it to xargs, you deleted `/usr`. A safer approach could start with `pkgutil --files org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11 | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'test -f /{} || echo "dir: /{}"'` replacing echo with desired actions... so that you don't recursively destroy directories. ALWAYS echo the commands you intend to run with `xargs` and inspect before you run them.